# Set cbar min and max for seaborn clustermap

Tags: python, seaborn

So I am trying to set the range for the colorbar in seaborn clustermap. The range it automatically generated is too large and the colors are not well represented. Is there a way to manually set the range?

Now my clustermap looks something like this:

[image: my clustermap[1]]

Following is my code:

```
zrf = pd.read_csv("zebrafish_results.csv", index_col="gene_name")
my_cmap = sns.diverging_palette(240, 10, n=9, as_cmap=True)
plot = sns.clustermap(zrf, figsize=(10,20),cmap=my_cmap)
```

Comment: I tried to set vmin to -1 (minimun value in my data is -0.27). However it did not work.  I also tried vmin = -10 and the range became [-8,8]. It seems to me that the color range will always be [-x, x] if there are negative values in data. For now I just rounded negative data to zero and it looks prettier now.

Comment: Please provide a sample data set to reproduce this behavior and you are more likely to find someone that will be able to assist you. You can either make one yourself, or look in `sns.load_dataset()`.